# Class loops itself until php is out of memory and db have too many connections

Tags: php, sql, oop, memory

I have some class which extends the Loader class. And those classes declared inside Loader class, like that -

```
class Loader
{   

    public $sql;
    public $logger;
    public $view;
    public $model;
    public $config;
    public $url_data;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $url_accepted = $_GET['url'];
        $this->config = $GLOBALS['config'];

        $database_connection = some array...
        $this->sql = new dbHandler($database_connection);

        $this->logger = new logger();

        $this->view = new view();
        $this->view->set_view($config['view']['view']);
        $this->model = new model();
        ...
        require_once("app/controllers/frame.php");
```

view and model are the classes extends Loader and also frame extends Loader but frame is also extended.
For some reason it looping itself until the sql have to many connections and php is out of memory, while index.php is the only place where Loader is declared -

```
require_once("app/includes/loader.php");

$loader = new Loader();
```

I don't know what is the problem but I know that the source is the declaring of view and model. Both model and view have no refrence to Loader, except in the "extends Loader" and accesing loader value by using $this.

The code on pastebin - http://pastebin.com/u/Yehonatan

Can someone help me solving this problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get your question, I could not relate the prime_class and sub_class with your loader class. Could you be more clear with your question

Answer (score 1):

> Both model and view have no refrence to Loader, except in the "extends Loader" and accesing loader value by using $this.

If this is the Sitation

```
class Loader {
  // ...
  public function __construct() {
    // ...
    $this->view = new view();
    // ...
    $this->model = new model();
  }
}

class view extends Loader { 
  // ...
}

class model extends Loader {
  // ...
}
```

You need to overwrite `__construct()` method. If you don't the model/view class will use the `__construct()` method of Loader which creates model/view objects -> *recursion*

Answer (score 1):

```
class Loader
   {   
    public $sql;
    public $logger;
    public $view;
    public $model;
    public $config;
    public $url_data;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $url_accepted = $_GET['url'];
        $this->config = $GLOBALS['config'];

        $database_connection = some array...
        $this->sql = new dbHandler($database_connection);

        $this->logger = new logger();

        $this->view = new view();
        $this->view->set_view($config['view']['view']);
        $this->model = new model();
        ...
        require_once("app/controllers/frame.php");
```

One more question, "extends Loader"  are you saying that your model and view classes extends loader ? If this is the case then it is very obvious that it will go through the recursion.
If this is the case then you will need to override the `__construct()` in the view and the model.

```
class View extends Loader 
{ 
   public function __construct() 
   { 
     // do something
   }
}

class Model extends Loader 
{
   public function __construct() 
   { 
     // do something
   }
}
```

I hope you understand the reason, if not I would be happy to explain.

Comment: Well, I did understood so I changed the __construct on Loader to load. Now it's working fine except one thing, while passing the variables view,model to frame class all of the variables vallues are NULL, although I never nulled them.

Comment: values like what ? You are using your index.php as a path to  your controllers right ? and I am not sure I understand what you mean by construct on Loader to load and frame class.

Comment: Loader class have a single function witch called 'load', the load function is called from index.php.
This is the Loader structer -
Index -> Loader -> $this(view,model,sql,logger,config,url_data) ->(passed to) -> frame.php which is an abstract class the extended by the user selection. But for some reason the $this values are passed to frame but they passed null.

Comment: Could you please paste your codes from view,model, index and loader to pastebin.com and add the link to your question that way others might be able to help you on this as well :)

Comment: XD, that's what I wanted to ask you, in a minute.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/u/Yehonatan - Here you go

Comment: You're not calling you're load() function anywhere (or am I missing something ) which could be the possible cause for your values being null. Loader class having __construct was just fine, you should have simply override __construct in the view and the model (if nothing to do just an empty method would do fine as well). I hope that all of your request passes through index.php hence Loader.php is called atleast once populating the values you need.

Comment: loader is called via index.php
<?php  

 require_once("app/includes/loader.php");  
 $loader = new Loader();  
 $loader->load();  
?>

And btw, frame and is extendor is called inside Loader

Comment: The problem is probably in frame class, maybe it's the constructor?